# Searching and matching - Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have `Column A` which contains aprox. 16.000 entries

- Numbers but on occasion it contains the word *net*
- Numbers sometimes repeat themselves (multiple entries in the list)

I have `Column C` that contains aprox. 300 entries

- these entries are only numbers (*no words*)
- they're unique but could match some in `Column A`

I'd like to do a **search** that would find any occurrence of a number from `Column C` in `Column A` and write in `Column B`, the word **Found**, next to the respective entry identified in `Column A`

Visual example:

[image]

I've looked into sorting, regex and conditional formatting but I can't quite find something that could accomplish this. 
I need a nudge in the right direction please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of [IF](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IF-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2), [ISERROR](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/IFERROR-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) and [VLOOKUP](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/VLOOKUP-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1):

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(C1,A:A,1,FALSE))=FALSE,"found","")
```

The VLOOKUP returns a match or an error. The ISERROR checks to see if the VLOOKUP has returned and error. The IF writes 'found' if the ISERROR = false.

Comment: The `=FALSE` is not needed if you switch the `"Found"` and the `""`

Answer (score 1):

I would enter in B1:
`=IF(COUNTIF(C$1:C$300;A1)>0;"found";"")`

and then copy it to B2 and below

(of course, if you have more then 300 entries in column C, you should increase range in the above example)

Comment: COUNTIF is not an array formula and has been optimized.  There is no detriment to using a full column reference: `COUNTIF(C:C;A1)`

Comment: Also the `>0` is not needed as anything above 0 will return True and `0` will Return False in the IF: `=IF(COUNTIF(C:C;A1);"found";"")`